# Add tap gesture to UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Im attempting to add a `UITapGesture` to a `UIStackView` within a collectionView cell but each time I do my app crashes. (All `IBOutlets` are connected) This there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
 let fGuesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.showF(_:)))
 cell.fstackView.addGestureRecognizer(fGuesture)

 func showF(sender: AnyObject){
        print(111)
    }
```

Comment: at the `#selector(self.` change `self` to your class name

Comment: Show us, how your crash looks (console output).

Comment: If you are using Swift 4, you need @objc on showF. Also, showF should include a _ for the parameter.

Answer (score 18):

Is the stackview enabled for touch ?
Try to set Userinteraction Parameter

```
cell.fstackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 3):

If the app is crashing due to `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` - you may need to add some delay before adding the gesture recognizer to the stack view.

If you are accessing the stack view property in the collection view cell subclass's init or in the collection view's delegate methods, the stack view may not have been initialized yet. Try using a timer or GCD to add a 0.1 second delay and it should work fine...

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(prepareStackView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

...

```
@objc func prepareStackView() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(stackViewTapped))
    myStackView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against timing solutions. They are brittle and can break for a number of reasons (newer devices run faster and break timing, new OS versions change the order things, etc). In this case I would recommend using a lifecycle event such as awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 2):

Set the gesture recognizer in the main thread:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.view.gestureRecognizers = [self.tapGestureRecognizer]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had UIButtons as subviews, so even if I added gesture to UIStackView, it ignored my gesture.

So I added the code

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

to make UIStackView receive my touch.