# Swift add GestureRecognizer to View on top of UIStackView

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uistackview

I'm trying to add a GestureRecognizer to a UIView which is an arranged subview of a UIStackView. I tried already this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193868/add-tap-gesture-to-uistackview) or [this](https://blog.thefuntasty.com/adopting-uistackview-fe330577d8d2). Also I tried to enable all underlying views for userInteraction, but it didn't work.

When I add the gesture recognizer to the imageView which is the parent view of the stackView, then the tap works. Strangely it also get's triggered when I tap on the "bannerView" which is a subview of the stackView and therefore lies on top of the imageView.

What's the proper way to get the tap gesture recognize on top of a stackViews's arrangedSubview?

Here my code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
var imageView: UIImageView!
var bannerStackView: UIStackView!
var bannerView: UIView!

override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view = view

    setupImageView()
    setupBannerStackView()
    setupConstraints()
}

func setupImageView() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "Apple.jpeg")
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(imageView)
}

func setupBannerStackView() {
    bannerStackView = UIStackView()
    bannerStackView.axis = .vertical
    bannerStackView.alignment = .leading
    bannerStackView.distribution = .equalCentering
    bannerStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    bannerView = UIView()
    bannerView.backgroundColor = .blue

    bannerStackView.addArrangedSubview(bannerView)
    imageView.addSubview(bannerStackView)

    /*
     Also tried this but didn't work
     */
//        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(onBannerTapped))
//        bannerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//        bannerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//        bannerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    for bannerView in bannerStackView.arrangedSubviews {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(onBannerTapped))
        bannerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        bannerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

}

@objc func onBannerTapped() {
    print("Banner view tapped!")
}

func setupConstraints() {
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    bannerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    bannerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    bannerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
}
```

Comment: I think it won't work. Because there is something like "Z-stack" which means that you have to click only on the top of the views. So you can add gesture only on the top of the Views

Comment: Looking at my code that's exactly what I'm doing: adding the GestureRecognizer to the "bannerView" which is the topmost view. (Just that I don't implement with SwiftUI which has Z-Stack). Any other ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.isUserInteractionEnabled` cascades to subviews. So, even if I set it to true on a subview, if the subview's superview (or its superview, and on up the hierarchy) has `.isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false`, the subview will not get touch events.

So, the first thing to do is check `.isUserInteractionEnabled` on each view in the hierarchy.

In your func, remove this line:

```
    bannerStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

then add these lines after creating your `tapGesture`:

```
    print("imageView isUserInteractionEnabled:", imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled)
    print("bannerStackView isUserInteractionEnabled:", bannerStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled)
    print("bannerView isUserInteractionEnabled:", bannerView.isUserInteractionEnabled)
```

So it looks like this:

```
func setupBannerStackView() {
    bannerStackView = UIStackView()
    bannerStackView.axis = .vertical
    bannerStackView.alignment = .leading
    bannerStackView.distribution = .equalCentering

    // remove this line (comment-it out)
    // bannerStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    bannerView = UIView()
    bannerView.backgroundColor = .blue

    bannerStackView.addArrangedSubview(bannerView)
    imageView.addSubview(bannerStackView)

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onBannerTapped))
    bannerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    print("view isUserInteractionEnabled:", view.isUserInteractionEnabled)
    print("imageView isUserInteractionEnabled:", imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled)
    print("bannerStackView isUserInteractionEnabled:", bannerStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled)
    print("bannerView isUserInteractionEnabled:", bannerView.isUserInteractionEnabled)

}
```

You should see this output:

```
view isUserInteractionEnabled: true
imageView isUserInteractionEnabled: false
bannerStackView isUserInteractionEnabled: true
bannerView isUserInteractionEnabled: true
```

and that tells you.... you simply need to add:

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```